# Caret and rpart - does caret automatically prune rpart trees

Tags: machine-learning, r, decision-trees

Question relating to the caret package 'rpart' method.

Does the method='rpart' automatically prune the tree?  If so, what rules does it follow?  If not, how does one go about directing caret to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*To give a proper background for `rpart` package and  `rpart` method with `caret` package:*

**1.** If you use the `rpart` package directly, it will construct the complete tree by default. 
If you want to prune the tree, you need to provide the optional parameter `rpart.control` which controls the fit of the tree. R documentation below, eg.:

```
    rpart(formula, data, method, control = prune.control)

    prune.control = rpart.control(minsplit = 20, 
                    minbucket =  round(minsplit/3), cp = 0.01, 
                    maxcompete = 4, maxsurrogate = 5, usesurrogate = 2, 
                    xval = 10, surrogatestyle = 0, maxdepth = 30 )
```

these are the hyper parameters you can tune to obtain a pruned tree.

One followed way is to not provide the ***cp*** i.e complexity parameter and perform cross validation (xval), something like:

```
    rpart.control(minsplit = 20, minbucket = round(minsplit/3), xval = 10)
```

complexity parameter *(cp)* can be thought of as a measure of *complexity/ no of splits* of your model and you want to increase complexity until your model generalizes to new observations. i.e. *regularization*

Therefore evaluate the *cross validated error vs cp* and choose the *cp* that gives the good value (cp_good).

Finally, add it as your control parameter i.e. *rpart.control(cp = cp_good)* or use the prune function i.e. *prune(fit, cp = cp_good)* to get the desired tree.

**2.** `caret` package on the other hand already implements the `rpart` method with `cp` as the tuning parameter. `caret` by default will prune your tree based on a default run it makes on a default parameter grid (even if you don't supply any `tuneGrid` and `trControl` while training your model:

```
    model <- train(data,
                   labels,
                   method = "rpart")
```

Comment: So, what I am hearing, is that it is not possible to specify how to prune an rpart tree within the caret package?

Comment: All mentioned above is included in rpart only. nothing out of it. rpart.control is one of the optional arguments of rpart. I edited first part of my R code to make it more clear.

Answer (score 3):

When I run the following R code

```r
ctrl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",
                     number = 10,
                     repeats = 3)

model <- train(trainingData,
               labels,
               method = "rpart",
               trControl = ctrl)
model
```

I get below output

```
CART 

760 samples
  6 predictor
  2 classes: 'Moving', 'Stationary' 

No pre-processing
Resampling: Cross-Validated (10 fold, repeated 3 times) 
Summary of sample sizes: 684, 684, 685, 684, 685, 684, ... 
Resampling results across tuning parameters:

  cp          Accuracy   Kappa    
  0.02310231  0.8640390  0.7224351
  0.10231023  0.8460257  0.6925546
  0.59075908  0.7273725  0.3787905

Accuracy was used to select the optimal model using the largest value.
The final value used for the model was cp = 0.02310231.
```

`cp` is the parameter used by `rpart` to determine when to prune. Thus it seems that the tree is already being pruned during the training when using `caret`. Consequently the answer to the question is **yes**.